# Android: repository pattern what is the best solution to create an object?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, kotlin, singleton, repository-pattern

This question is about the OOP(class/interface) design.

I am developing an android library, not an app.
The app will use this library. 
This library is developed by Repository pattern.

One repository and 2 data sources (local, remote).

Because the local data source uses "SharedPreference", it needs Context.

Below is my repository interface and implements.

```
interface MyRepository {

    fun create(String data)

    fun get(key: String): String
}

class MyRepositoryImpl(
        private val localDataSource: LocalDataSource,
        private val remoteDataSource: RemoteDataSource
): MyRepository {

    fun create(String data) {
        localDataSource.create(data);
        remoteDataSource.create(data);
    }

    fun get(key: String): String {
        // temp code
        return localDataSource.get(key)
    }

    companion object {

        private var instance: MyRepository? = null

        fun getInstance(context: Context): MyRepository {
            if (instance == null) {
                val localDataSource: LocalDataSource = LocalDataSourceImpl.getInstance(context)
                val remoteDataSource: RemoteDataSource = RemoteDataSourceImpl.getInstance()
                instance = MyRepositoryImpl(localDataSource, remoteDataSource)
            }

            return instance!!
        }

    }
}
```

The MyRepositoryImpl is implemented by the Singleton pattern.
Because it should be used anywhere in the app.
So the app developers should be able to get the instance of MyRepository like:

```
val myRepository = MyRepositoryImpl.getInstance(context)
val data = myRepository.get("key")
```

But It looks weird... "getInstance(context)".
I think this is not a good approach.
Is there any more smart design, please?

Comment: The fact that `MyRepositoryImpl` can't be constructed independently, but needs to be given some other info, suggests to me that it's not really a singleton.  (Which is why it ‘looks weird’, or in other words the code smells!)  I'd suggest either renaming `getInstance()` to something indicating this, e.g. along the lines of `instanceFor()` which could potentially cache multiple instances, one for each context; or if there could only ever be one context, give the class a way to discover the context for itself, and make it a proper singleton.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Kotlin you can use **object** keyword to implement singleton pattern in a thread-safe way. There's no need to define getInstance method in your companion object. Simply define your `MyRepository` class as object like below. By overloading invoke operator you'll be able to pass the context useful to initialize your localDataSource and remoteDataSource instances.

```kotlin
object MyRepository  {
    private lateinit var localDataSource: LocalDataSource
    private lateinit var remoteDataSource: RemoteDataSource

    operator fun invoke(context: Context): MyRepository {
        //...
        localDataSource = LocalDataSourceImpl.getInstance(context)
        remoteDataSource = RemoteDataSourceImpl.getInstance(context)
        return this
    }
}
```

This code will be compiled to the following java code (static initialization block) :

```java
public final class MyRepository {
   public static final MyRepository INSTANCE;

   private SomeSingleton() {
      INSTANCE = (MyRepository) this;
   }

   static {
      new MyRepository();
   }
}
```

This way you'll be able to get an instance of your MyRepository class like a normal, non-object class, simply by doing:

```
val repo = MyRepository(this) // this is your context
```

Each method you define within the `MyRepository` class will be accessible like it was a java static method, so you'll be able to call it like:

```
MyRepository.myMethod()
```

More details [here](https://medium.com/@BladeCoder/kotlin-singletons-with-argument-194ef06edd9e)

Comment: But how would such an object known which Context to use to get the LocalDataSource it needs to create the MyRepository instance?

Comment: I've updated my response, you can use operator overloading on invoke function

Comment: Thank you, I need to see the 'operator' keyword more! :)